# What's the most efficient way to make immutable and mutable versions of an objective-c class?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, immutability, mutable

Suppose I’m making an Objective-C class that represents a fraction, and want to create immutable and mutable versions.

Following the patterns in the Foundation framework, you might expect to see the method `fractionByAddingFraction:` in the immutable version and `addFraction:` in the mutable version.

The paradox I’m running into is how to only include the fraction-adding logic once between the two classes. It seems that the immutable `fractionByAddingFraction:` method needs to know about (and make use of) the mutable `addFraction:` method in order to avoid code duplication, and yet including the mutable methods in the implementation of the immutable class means they could conceivably be called on the immutable object, which defeats the point.

A brief explanation (or better still, a continuation of this simplified example) would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your class example seems to represent a _value object_, so I don't think you should provide a mutable version for it. __Just make it immutable.__

Comment: @Jordão For this particular example, you're quite right. I just felt that this was the easiest and most concise way to explain my confusion about the concept in general (as it pertains to more complicated classes). Any thoughts on how it would be done regardless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is correct (if you really need a mutable subclass, which you should avoid unless you actually need it). I'm not quite clear where the confusion is coming in. You would most easily implement `addFraction:` using `fractionByAddingFraction:`. It would be a little inefficient, but that's the direction that would make the most sense. Something like:

```
- (void)addFraction:(Fraction *)anotherFraction {
   Fraction *newFraction = [self fractionByAddingFraction:anotherFraction];
   self.internalStuff = newFraction.internalStuff;
}
```

But typically you would probably handle this more efficiently with some private `_GetInternalStuffByAddingInternalStuffs()` function that both classes would use.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I had avoided the first approach simply because, as you mentioned, it can be inefficient to create a new object every time any of its components are changed. Your idea of making a private function seems like a good alternative, however I’m wondering where the function would ideally be located to be accessible to both classes' implementations, yet inaccessible to anything else (which rules out putting it in a header)?

Comment: This is typically done with a private header such as Fraction+Private.h. Note that you may still want to consider ditching the mutable form if it's this kind of thing. Note how NSNumber has no mutable form. Unless you're creating many of them very fast, the simplicity and thread-safety of value objects makes them very attractive. Even if you do make them very quickly, you can cache some of them. NSNumber caches the integers -1-12 as singletons as I recall. You can do that kind of caching most easily with immutable objects. But the above is how you handle it when you need mutability.

Comment: Remember that you can go and look at how the underlying CoreFoundation objects are implemented: http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-635/CFArray.c.

Answer (score 0):

The primary implementations of Foundation’s collections cheat: there’s only one implementation, which is a subclass of `NSMutableFoo`, and it has a private mutability flag. This means client code can’t test whether a particular object is mutable or not, but that would never be a good idea anyway except perhaps for debugging and assertions.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that 'NSFoo' would be a subclass of 'NSMutableFoo', and that 'NSMutableFoo' would contain all methods for both classes, however limit its immutable subclass' ability to use the mutable ones based on the private flag?

Comment: `NSFoo` isn’t a subclass of `NSMutableFoo`, no. The relationship is generally `NSFoo` ← `NSMutableFoo` ← `NSCFFoo`, where `NSCFFoo` is a concrete implementation. `NSCFFoo`’s mutating methods check the mutable flag and throw an exception if it’s immutable. (Reality is actually more complex than this because of toll-free bridging, but that’s how it would work without CF being involved.) For your own classes, you’d probably call the concrete subclass something like `XYConcreteFoo`.